# Javascript hoisting odd behavior

Tags: javascript

How does hoisting explain this behavior?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("i is: " + i);
    }, i * 200);
}
```

The output of this is 4, 4, 4, 4.

This is used as a dangerous example of hoisting often in literature. It makes sense that the latter outputs may be 4 since the i variable is bound to function scope and as such is shared between all calls and by the time they execute i will be 4 having finished the for loop. However, the initial call specifies a timeout of 0 * 200 or 0 and as such I feel this should execute immediately while i is still less than 4. What causes all the output from this function to be 4's?

Comment: It doesn't because it has nothing to do with hoisting. And even if you pass `0` as delay, the minimal delay in browsers is about 10ms.

Comment: I figured as much, the examples I have been reading online are misleading. I.e. http://thecomputersarewinning.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't because it has nothing to do with hoisting.

And even if you pass `0` as delay, the minimal delay in browsers is about 10ms. Whatever delay you pass, the function is never executed immediately.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#Notes):

> It's important to note that if the function or code snippet cannot be executed until the thread that called `setTimeout()` has terminated.

So, before any of the callbacks is called, the `for` loop already terminated.

Related questions:

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
- [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful/779785)

Answer (score 1):

> *"However, the initial call specifies a timeout of 0 * 200 or 0 and as such I feel this should execute immediately..."*

It could be that that may happen in an environment that can take advantage of multiple threads, but in a single threaded environment, the current synchronous flow of execution will continue unfettered until complete.

This means that the loop continues and finishes before the first `setTimeout` callback happens.

Even if your loop took *10,000 milliseconds* to complete, the loop will be allowed to continue before the first callback would fire.

---

Try this demo:

```
var start = Date.now();

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

     // set up the first timeout
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("i is: " + i);
    }, i * 200);

    while (Date.now() - start < 1000) ; // block for 1000 ms
}
```

After the first `setTimeout` has been set up, we block for 1000ms. The result of the `alert()` calls is still the same. This is because the synchronous flow continues irrespective of any asynch code that is scheduled to run.

Answer (score 0):

The four *calls* to setTimeout fire within the loop before the first timer expires (and the anonymous method call fires). As a result, when it does fire, the result is always 4. setTimeout timer delays are never guaranteed.